# How does the .html() d3.js method function in this example?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, methods

**post edited with complete code:**

this is my first post so please tell me if I'm wrong in any way.

I'm a university student (communication) and I'm triyng to do a little project to pass an exam.

My goal is to make a time table for Radio programs with javascript and D3. **I know there are best way... but these are the topic of the course, so I have to use them.**

I had a big help from a friend of mine who has given me this suggestion to put a link inside every `<td>` of the table:

Here it is the complete HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "it">
    <head>
        <title>Palinsesto</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="CoronaVirus.png" sizes= "130x130">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stilePalinsesto.css" media="all">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="TabellaPalinsesto.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body><!-- il body è costruito in javascript --> </body>
</html>
```

and this is TabellaPalinsesto.js

```
 /* inserimento titolo h2 e paragrafo */
d3.select("body")
    .append("h2")
    .text("Palinsesto programmi 2021")
d3.select("body")
    .append("p")
    .text("Qui trovate la nostra programmazione settimanale: cliccate sul nome del proogramma per aprire la pagina relativa")

/* inserimento dell'intestazion della tabella con le relative etichette */
d3.select("body")
    .append("table")
    .append("thead")
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(["dalle", "alle", "LUNEDI", "MARTEDI", "MERCOLEDI", "GIOVEDI",
        "VENERDI", "SABATO", "DOMENICA"
    ])
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function (d) { return d });

d3.select("table")
    .append("tbody")
    .enter();

/*divisione di ogni dato array in 3 parti ProgrammaNome, ProgrammaUrl e datoClasse */
d3.csv("Palinsesto.csv", function (datiCaricati) {
    console.log(datiCaricati);
    var d = datiCaricati;
    d3.select("tbody")
        .append("tr")
        .selectAll("td")
        .data([d.dalle, d.alle, d.LUNEDI, d.MARTEDI, d.MERCOLEDI, d.GIOVEDI, d.VENERDI, d.SABATO, d.DOMENICA])
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .html(function (cella) {
                const [ProgrammaNome, ProgrammaUrl, classeCella] = cella.split("|");
                /* se la cella ha il valore dell'url, inserisco un link */
                if (ProgrammaUrl) {
                   return "<a href='" + ProgrammaUrl + "' target='blank' \">" + ProgrammaNome + "</a>"
                }
                /* altrimenti mostro un testo normale */
                /*Se non ci fosse le colonne "dalle" e "alle" non verrebbero visualizzate */
                else {
                    return ProgrammaNome
                }
              }
             )
    
});
```

I dont understand very well:

```
.html(function (cella)
```

How .html method works in javascript? Where can I find any docs?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_html) help answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is related to the use of d3.js, which indeed has a .html() method as @AndrewReid correctly stated (and linked to the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_html)). It is similar to the .text() method, which sets the .innerText property of element(s), but it sets the .innerHTML property of the element(s) in the current selection.

What the .html() method does is the following:

- If it is passed a value, it simply sets the innerHTML of the element(s) to that value
- If it is passed a function (as in your example), it evaluates the function and sets the innerHTML of the element(s) to the function return value.

  - The function is fed the arguments: (d, i, nodes), where d is the current datum and i is the current index, and nodes is the current selection.

Let's start with a simple example (see code snippet below):

- I defined some example data (`myData`), which I think might closely resemble what yours looks like based on the code.
- Ignore the "thead" "tr" and "th" creation, for now, the section after `// create the table header:`
- Focus on the "tbody" "tr" and "td" creation, for now, the section after `// create the table body:`
- (The "outer loop") We select all "tr" (and none exist), so the selection is empty, but then we bind `myData` to this selection, and then `.enter()` this selection. This essentially means, we enter a selection equal to the length of our data, and at each item in our data, we can do something - i.e. we can `.append("tr")`. This means we will create N new "tr" elements, where N is equal to `myData.length`.
- (The "inner loop") Then we repeat this process but one level deeper, by binding the empty "td" selection to a new array of data, equal to the current values of the outer loop's iteration. We wrote it manually here, but we could have written `.data(d => Object.values(d))`.
- We then `.enter()` this inner loop's iteration, and we create M new "td" elements, where M is equal to `Object.values(myData[i])`, where `i` is the current index of the outer loop.
- Therefore, we can summarize by saying, that we iterate over the rows of our data and create the corresponding "tr" elements, and then within each row, we iterate of the columns of our data and create the corresponding "td" elements. However, these "td" elements are empty at this point, and this is where .html() comes in:
- We can pass a function to .html() as stated earlier, and the `d` argument that is passed in, is equal to the current data item of the iteration, that was bound with `.data(...)`. So in our case, this means firstly `'mon1|www.mon1.com|some-class'`, then `'tue1|www.tue1.com|some-class'`, and then `'wed1|www.wed1.com|some-class'` and then we have finished our first inner loop and we progress with the next iteration of the outer loop (and its inner loop).
- The function that we passed into .html() then simply splits the string on the `"|"` character and proceeds to construct an anchor tag "a" with the corresponding class, href, and innerText.

```js
const myData = [
  {mon: 'mon1|www.mon1.com|some-class', tue: 'tue1|www.tue1.com|some-class', wed: 'wed1|www.wed1.com|some-class'},
  {mon: 'mon2|www.mon2.com|some-class', tue: 'tue2|www.tue2.com|some-class', wed: 'wed2|www.wed2.com|some-class'}
]

// create the table header:
d3.select("table")
    .append("thead")
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(Object.keys(myData[0]))
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(d => d);

// create the table body:
d3.select("table")
    .append("tbody")
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(d => [d.mon, d.tue, d.wed]) // Object.values(d)
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .html(function(d) {
        const [ProgrammaNome, ProgrammaUrl, classeCella] = d.split("|");
        return `<a class="${classeCella}" href="${ProgrammaUrl}" target="blank">${ProgrammaNome}</a>`;      
      }
    )
```

```css
table, table td, table th {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Note, you technically don't need to use .html() for this example, you could do it like this:

```js
const myData = [
  {mon: 'mon1|www.mon1.com|some-class', tue: 'tue1|www.tue1.com|some-class', wed: 'wed1|www.wed1.com|some-class'},
  {mon: 'mon2|www.mon2.com|some-class', tue: 'tue2|www.tue2.com|some-class', wed: 'wed2|www.wed2.com|some-class'}
]

// create the table header:
d3.select("table")
    .append("thead")
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(Object.keys(myData[0]))
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(d => d);

// create the table body:
d3.select("table")
    .append("tbody")
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(d => [d.mon, d.tue, d.wed])
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .append("a")
    .attr("class", d => d.split("|")[2])
    .attr("href", d => d.split("|")[1])
    .text(d => d.split("|")[0]);
```

```css
table, table td, table th {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

If you want to visualize the inner and outer loops, maybe this example will help. (i, j) = (row, col):

[image]

```js
const myData = [
  {mon: 'mon1|www.mon1.com|some-class', tue: 'tue1|www.tue1.com|some-class', wed: 'wed1|www.wed1.com|some-class'},
  {mon: 'mon2|www.mon2.com|some-class', tue: 'tue2|www.tue2.com|some-class', wed: 'wed2|www.wed2.com|some-class'}
]

// create the table header:
d3.select("table")
    .append("thead")
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(Object.keys(myData[0]))
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(d => d);

// create the table body:
d3.select("table")
    .append("tbody")
    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data((d,i) => [i, i, i])
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text((i,j) => `${i},${j}`);
```

```css
table, table td, table th {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: Really thanks to you... I'll study what you said :-)

Comment: Your very welcome. Good Luck. d3.js has a bit of a steep learning curve but once it clicks it's very powerful. If my answer solved your question, then please consider to mark it as accepted. Thanks.